# Deploy the absolute inequality formua

Tags: discrete-mathematics, inequality, absolute-value

Please help me derive that equation: 
$$f(x) =
\begin{cases}
1,  & \text{if $(x-a)^2-(x-b)^2>0$} \\
-1, & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$
where $x,a,b \ge 0$

Thank you in advance

This is what I done. However, I am not sure about my answer

**Solution:**
Due to $x,a,b \ge 0$ then
$$(x-a)^2-(x-b)^2>0$$ 
$$\equiv (x-a)^2>(x-b)^2$$
$$\equiv |x-a|>|x-b|$$

And othersolution is
$$(x-a)^2-(x-b)^2>0$$ 
$$-2ax+a^2>-2bx+b^2$$
$$2x(b-a)>(b-a)(b+a)$$
$$x>\frac{b+a} 2 \text {if b>a} $$
or
$$x<\frac{b+a} 2 \text {if b $\le$ a} $$

Comment: Minor comment, if $b=a$ we cannot conclude that the inequality holds if $x\lt \frac{a+b}{2}$.

Comment: Yes. It is only preresult. Could you see it and let me know which is correct?

Comment: The first is right. The second is almost right, if you replace $b\le a$ by $b\lt a$, and note that we cannot have $(x-a)^2-(x-b)^2\gt 0$ if $b=a$.

Comment: Thanks. How to rewrite it in to $f$ function?

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by "deploy," or what you mean by deriving the equation. It looks like a *definition* of $f(x)$.

Comment: Sorry about my English skill. My goal is rewrite the $f$ function to make more simple explanation. In the original equation, we have root square inequality. I want to based the condition of x to make the $f$ function more easy and short

Answer (score 1):

It's easier to remark that $$(x-a)^2-(x-b)^2= \left((x-a)-(x-b)\right)\left((x-a)+(x-b)\right)= (b-a)(2x-(a+b))$$

Hence

$x > \frac{a+b}{2}$ if $b>a$ and $x < \frac{a+b}{2}$ if $b<a$

and it holds for all x,a,b reals